# Centering an unordered list in DIV while keeping last row of LIs adjusted to the left

Tags: html, css

using latest Bootstrap, I have an unordered list containing images like a grid:

```
<div id="featured-products" class="container">

      <ul>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
      </ul>

</div>
```

I have centered the unordered list with `text-align: center`:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the last row is not adjusted to the left if the row is uncomplete, i.e. a list item is missing.

Is there a way to pull the last row to the left while keeping the ul centered within the div? The solutions has to be responsive.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us the whole code?

Comment: is there a reason you can't just change the text-align to left?

Comment: Unless you are limited by your design, else, I'd suggest wrapping your <ul> with a <div>, set width of <ul> and centre the <ul> in the <div>. simply float all your <li> left and they will align

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a9tmhuaf/

Comment: A possible solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNZNvJ

Comment: The problem is that the unordered list is not centered with the container. It is floating to the left.

Comment: I just updated the example.

Comment: Sorry, but that is still not centered in relation the the containing element; in your example the body, in my example the container.

Answer (score 0):

center the list container, not it's contents.

Here's an example

```
ul {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

also consider using Mansonry for image galleries
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

[image]    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: left; // this will make last row align left;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        width:800px;
        margin:0 auto;  // this will center in page;
    }

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

use making to center to page, than use align left to make last row behave like you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/a9tmhuaf/1/

Comment: Still the same effect. The unordered list is not centered.

Comment: it's works in chrome and safari, didn't look at other one.  but it should.. i uploaded a pic, is that what you trying to do?

Comment: The problem is that it is not responsive any longer. It uses a fixed width. It has to work with the standard Bootstrap container.

Comment: than instead of fixed width add width:100%; should do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/a9tmhuaf/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle show exactly the same output. Everything is aligned to the left inlcuding the UL.

Comment: that's why you need to fill in your bootstrap's container width with max-width, see how that is comment out?